# What is the difference betweet 2.2 API and 4.2.2 API on SDK Manager

Tags: android, performance, mobile, sdk

I am a beginner on android programming. I am at the first at all. I wanna learn some important point.

Now, I am installing the programs and platforms which I need to develop Android Apps. On the SDK Manager there are few options to download Android API.

Which one should I prefer? I want to that, my app will run on all android roms and versions like ICS or JellyBean.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to support as many users as you can, you should opt for the lowest version API, since apps written for an older version of Android will work for future versions as well (although they may not be optimal).  Once you need a feature in a later version, you can increment your minimum SDK version.

I would look through the different SDK versions ([e.g. 2.1](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.1.html)) and see which features (and/or permissions) you need for your app.

Keep in mind that older phones may not have certain capabilities, and you may not be able to support them.  Therefore you should weigh if what you're adding is worth alienating the users you will no longer be able to support.  Android provides a [table](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) of market share per version.

You mention that you want to support ICS (4.0) and Jellybean (4.1 and 4.2), which together control a little less than 50% of the Android market.  It is worth looking into supporting Gingerbread (2.3) as well for another 45%.

Another option of course is to branch your code depending on the user's OS version, but this requires a little more maintenance work.  However, if you are supporting pre- and post-Holo-themed versions (ie for the action bar), it may not add that much overhead.

It really depends on your target market, purpose, and familiarity with Android.

Answer (score 1):

Android maintains *forward-compatibility* which means an app designed for 2.1 for example will work on later versions (in most cases). However there are some features added in later versions which are only supported starting with a certain SDK version.

[This](http://www.learncomputer.com/android-sdk-which-version-to-use/) page may be helpful for you